# Change a specific color in an area

Tags: inkscape, png, background, color-conversion

I have this image, a PNG file:
[image]

Question: I want to change one of the logo's color to be more visible than the others.
The color I want is australium gold rgb(231, 181, 59)

These "logo's" represent the 9 classes in Team Fortress 2.

I tried the manual stuff but its not practical, plus I can't reproduce the fading color at the edges:

[image]

Comment: You are trying to manipulate a raster image using vector graphic software. Why?

Comment: Because Inkscape is the first software that popped in my mind. I should use gimp, right? @Juancho

Comment: Not in Inkscape. PNG is a raster format. Inkscape is a vector image editor. It can't edit raster images. You need a raster image editor, like GIMP/Photsohop etc.

Comment: It /would/ work in Inkscape, though. There are filters available for replacing colors. The duochrome filter would be possible, for example (Filters > Color > Duochrome). Or the lightness/contrast filter, if the object is used as a mask. But honestly, Gimp is the better choice here :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use gimp, select the area than chose Colors > Colorize, then chose the color you want:

[image]